# Swift manipulating huge amount of data and displaying it correctly using queues

Tags: ios, swift, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having threads issue that i just can't figure out.

```
private func addTextToOutputView(_ text: String){
    var t = text
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var recentText = self.outputTextView.text

        self.responseLogQueue.async {
            if let firstChar = t.first, let index = t.index(of: firstChar) {
                if firstChar == "\n" {
                    let subS = t[index...]
                    t = String(subS)
                }
            }
        }
        let currentTime = Date()
        let currentTimeString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: currentTime)
        t = "\n\(currentTimeString) \(t)"

        recentText?.append(t)

        self.outputTextView.text = recentText

        if self.isScenarioOuputRunning {
            if self.outputTextView.text.count > 0 {
                let bottom = NSMakeRange(self.outputTextView.text.count-1, 1)
                self.outputTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connecting to a BLE device that is sending lots of data and fast.

I need to display the data in the order it arrived.

This work until a certain point here the app just getting stuck when there is too much data.

I just can't figure out how to set it that i will get the data that is already displayed (need to do that on the main queue?) then manipulate it (on my own backend queue) and then display to concatenated data again to the screen (a textview).

Anything i've tried didn't do it, if i encapsulate in a global queue (my queue) and then call just the get and set parts in the main queue, i'm loosing part of the data, and in this way i'm getting all the data correctly but with a huge chunks of data i have, the app getting stuck at a certain point

Any one See the issue?

The disturbing thing is that in OBJ-C same code (logic - line by line) exactly is working great!

Comment: Why are you dispatching code that updates `t` asynchronously on `responseLogQueue` but then using `t` in the current block? Perhaps you meant for the code that begins `let currentTime =` to be dispatched on the main queue inside the `responseLogQueue` block?

Comment: What is the code on the `responseLogQueue` supposed to achieve anyway?  It doesn't change `t`

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, 10x for the answer, the code is meant to do all the string manipulations on the back queue (Why do you day it does nothing?) Only the display things happen on the main queue and all the other happen on the back thread... isn't that correct? And why should the currentTime happen on the main queue

Comment: Because the code you have shown takes the first character from `t` and then takes the index of this character (which is going to be the first index) and then if the first character is `\n` then it creates `t` from `t`. It is a much more complicated way of saying `t = t`. Even if it did something, you can't dispatch that work on another queue and then continue to use `t` in the current queue; the background work won't have executed yet. Also, the work you are putting on the background queue isn't CPU intensive. Why not just do everything on the main queue?

Comment: @Paulw11I understand the issue you pointer out. There is a huge amount of data coming from 10/20 callbacks simultaneously every 200 milliseconds, and need to be displayed in the textfield... when the text starts to get longer the app jsut get stuck because there is too much work...

Comment: Possibly, although a modern iOS device is pretty fast. Your code isn't helping you. Get rid of the `responseLogQueue` dispatch or move all of the text processing into that closure and dispatch the UI update back to the main queue from inside that closure. Even then you will have concurrency problems. I would suggest that you not fetch the current text from the text view directly; you should keep a variable that you update from a serial dispatch queue and then have a task that you dispatch on then main queue to update the text view from that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You code doesn't make a lot of sense;  You are dispatching some code that updates `t` onto another queue, but then using `t` in the current thread to update the text view.  Also, the code that you have dispatched onto `responseLogQueue` effectively does `t = String(t)`

I would suggest that you don't use the textview itself as a data model; it should just be a view onto your text, which is stored in a string property.  You can use a serial dispatch queue to update this string property and a timer to periodically refresh the UI:

```
 class SomeViewController {

     var outputTextView: UITextView!

     private var refreshTimer: Timer?
     private var outputText = ""
     private var responseLogQueue: DispatchQueue!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.responseLogQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"ResponseLogQueue")
         self.timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            if self.isScenarioOuputRunning && !strongSelf.outputText.isEmpty {
                strongSelf.outputTextView.text = strongSelf.outputText
                let bottom = NSMakeRange(strongSelf.outputTextView.text.count-1, 1)
                strongSelf.outputTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
            }
        })
    }

    private func addTextToOutputView(_ text: String) {
        let currentTimeString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        let newText = "\n\(currentTimeString) \(text)"
        self.responseLogQueue.async {
            self.outputText = self.outputText.append(newText)
        }
    }
}
```